# How to prove that finding a successor n-1 times in the BST from the minimum node is O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, big-o, binary-search-tree

How to prove that finding a successor n-1 times in the BST from the minimum node is O(n)?

The questions is that we can create sorted order by

1) let the node = minimum node of the BST.

2) From that node, we recursively call find a successor.

I was told that the result is O(n) but I do not understand and do not know how to prove it.

Should not it be O(n*log n) instead? Because for the step 1, it is **O(log n)**, for the step 2, it is also **O(log n)** but it is called **n-1** times. Therefore, it will be **O(n*log n)**

Please clarify my doubt. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that any *individual* operation might take O(log n) time, so if you perform those operations n times, you should get a runtime of O(n log n).  This bound is correct, but it's not *tight*.  The actual runtime is Θ(n).

One way to see this is to look at any individual edge in the tree.  How many times will you visit each edge if you start at the leftmost node and repeatedly perform a successor query?  If you look closely at how the operations work, you'll discover that every edge is visited exactly twice: once downward and once upward.  Since all the work done is done traversing up and down edges, this means that the total amount of work done is proportional to twice the number of edges.  In any tree, the number of edges is the number of nodes minus one, and so the total work done is Θ(n).

To formalize this as a proof, try showing that you never descend down the same edge twice and that when you ascend up an edge, you never descend down that edge again.  Once you've done this, the conclusion that the runtime is Θ(n) follows from the above logic.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you :)
I am quite new to proof in algorithm. So, is there any hint on how to prove that each edge is not visited more than two times. I think of proving by contradiction. However, I do not know how to continue.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to post this as a comment on templatetypedef's answer, but it's too long.

His answer is right in that the easiest way to see that this is linear is because every edge is visited exactly twice, and the number of edges in a tree is always one less than the number of nodes (because every node has one parent, except the root!).

The issue is that the way he phrases the formal proof uses words that seem to imply contradiction as the way to go. In general, mathematicians frown on using contradiction because it often produces proofs with superfluous content. For instance:

```
Proof that  2 + 2 != 5:
Assume for contradiction that 2 + 2 = 5 (<- Remove this line)
Well 2 + 2 = 4
And 4 != 5
Contradiction! (<- Remove this line)
```

Contradiction tends to be verbose, and sometimes it can even obfuscate the idea behind the proof! There are times when contradiction seems pretty much necessary, but it's relatively rare and that's a separate discussion.

In this case, I don't see a proof by contradiction being any easier than a direct proof. On the other hand, regardless of proof technique, this proof is pretty ugly to do formally. Here's an attempt:

1) The `succ(n)` algorithm traverses one of two paths

- In the first case every edge is visited on the simple path from a node to the leftmost node of its right subtree
- In the other case, the node `n` has no right child in which case we go up its ancestors `p_1, p_2, p_3, ..., p_k` such that `p_(k-1)` is the *first ancestor* which is the left child of it's parent. All of those edges are visited in that simple path

We want to show that an arbitrary edge is traversed in precisely two `succ()` calls, once for the first case of `succ()` and once for the second case of `succ()`. Well, this is true for every edge other than the rightmost branch, but you can handle those edge cases separately. Alternatively we could prove the simpler argument where we return to the root after visiting the last element

This is two-fold because for a given edge `e` we have to find the `n1` and `n2` such that `succ(n1)` traverses `e` and `succ(n2)` also traverses `e`, as well as prove that every other `succ()` generates a path which does not include `e`.

2) First we actually prove that for each type of path that `succ()` visits, no two paths overlap (i.e. if `succ(n)` and `succ(n')` both traverse paths of the same type, those paths share no edges)

- In the first case, the simple path is precisely defined as follows. Start at node `n` and go one edge to the right to `r`. Then traverse the left branch of the subtree rooted at `r`. Now consider any other such path that starts at some other node `n'` (note, we don't assume that `n != n'`). It must go right one node to `r'`. Then it traverses the leftmost branch of the subtree rooted at `r'`. If the paths overlap then pick one of the edges that overlap. If it's `(n,r) = (n',r')` then we have `n = n'` and so it's the same path. If it's some `e = e'` in both leftmost branches then you can show, again, that `n = n'` (you can trace the leftmost branches and show that every edge is the same, then finally reach the conclusion that `r = r' => n = n'` because for a tree the parent is unique. You'll see this tracing argument below). Thus we know that for any `n` and `n'`, if their paths overlap, they are actually the same node! The contrapositive says this: if they are different nodes, then their paths don't overlap. That's exactly what we want (and the contrapositive is always equally true to the original statement).
- In the second case we define the simple path starting at node `n` and go up the ancestors `p_1, p_2, ..., p_k = g` until we reach the first node `p_k` such that `p_(k-1)` is to the left of `p_k`. Consider some other path of the same type that starts at node `n'` where `n != n'`. Similarly it visits `p_1', p_2', ..., p_k' = g'`. Because it's a tree, none of those ancestors are the same as the first set. Because none of the nodes on the two paths are the same, none of the edges can be the same and hence `succ(n)` and `succ(n')` do not traverse any of the same edges

3) Now we just need to show that at least one path of each type exists for a given edge. Well take any such edge `e = (c,p)` (note here I am ignoring the special edges on the rightmost branch which are technically only visited once and I am also ignoring the special edges on the leftmost branch which are technically visited once by `find_min()` and then once by `succ()` calls)

- If it's from a left child `c` to its parent `p` then `succ(c)` will cover the second type of path. To find the other path, keep going up `p`'s ancestors `p_1, p_2, ..., p_k` such that `p_(k-1)` is to the right of `p_k`. `succ(p_k)` will traverse a path containing `e` by definition (since `e` is on the leftmost branch of the subtree of `p_(k-1)` which is `p_k`'s right child).
- A similar argument holds for symmetric case when `c` is the right child of `p`

To summarize the proof we've shown that `succ()` generates two types of path. For each type of path, all of the paths of those types do not overlap. Furthermore, for any edge we have at least one of each of those types of paths. Since we call `succ()` on *every node* we can finally conclude that each edge is traversed twice (and hence the algorithm is `Theta(n)`).

Despite how long this proof was, it isn't actually complete (even ignoring the points when I explicitly said I was skipping details!). There are cases where I said something exists without proving it exists. You can figure out those details if you want and it is actually really satisfying to get it completely right (in my opinion at least. Maybe when you're a genius you'll find it tedious, heh)

Hope this helped. Let me know if you want me to clarify some steps

Comment: This is a great answer.  I was actually deliberately leaving some of the details out of my answer because this is a common homework problem and I didn't want to give everything away.

Comment: @templatetypedef Yeah I totally understand. I see reasons why it could be beneficial and reasons why it could be harmful, but it's a separate philosophical debate which side is more compelling. Glad you approved of the answer, I actually wasn't sure if it worked since there were so many small lemmas and edge cases I skipped.